# Reading values from xml document

Tags: c#, xml, cxml

I have an cXML that I am trying to read some values from....
I can read the node values using following code. But I am having hard time 
reading the "payloadID" from the same document. Any suggestions how to go about it?

```
XmlDocument xmlRequest = new XmlDocument();
XmlNodeList name = xmlRequest.GetElementsByTagName("NetworkID");
string sSecret = name[0].InnerText;

<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.023/cXML.dtd">
    <cXML payloadID="1348609345562-715426217594539696@216.109.111.69"
        timestamp="2012-09-11T11:55:53-07:00" version="1.2.023"
        xml:lang="en-US">      
        <From>
            <Credential domain="NetworkID">
                <Identity>tnt</Identity>
            </Credential>
        </From>
        <To>
            <Credential domain="NetworkID1">
                <Identity>abc</Identity>
            </Credential>
        </To>            
    </cXML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the root element and then use its Attributes property to read the attributes of that root element, e.g.:

```
XmlNode root = doc.SelectSingleNode("/cXML");
string attrVal = root.Attributes["payloadID"].Value;
```